# Parallel Tasks vs Multiple Processes

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I am trying to design systems to implement my complex business process. I am trying to decide which approach would be better considering the below scenario.

The are multiple parallel tasks that are a part of the process. Is it better to have them as parallel tasks in BPMN, as described in the first image or have multiple processes that are interacting with each other as described in the second image?

The systems being de-coupled in the second diagram gives me the freedom to change things w/o worrying too much about the consequences to the entire process. Something like Microservices.

I am not limited by the system but as of now I am planning to use a combination of Camunda and custom APIs which generates triggers based on business logic.

**Single Process**
[image: Single Process]

**Multiple Processess**

[image: Multiple Processes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is one process, you should model it as one process. So your first solution is definetely the better one.
If you want to decouple things a bit: Instead of creating separate processes have a look at the concept of the call activity or subprocesses. With these elements you can encapsulate certain aspects of the logic and still model one whole process.

(BTW: in your first picture, I would replace the inclusive gateway with a parallel one because you also split the flow with a parallel gateway.)

Comment: the business process is a single process as we need to optimise for readability there. On the systems side of things, I believe we are free to model it the way we want to. Also, can you please detail on what would be the benefits of keeping it a single process

Comment: @KevalDoshi The benefits of modelling it as one process are a better readability, a better understanding and better control when executing the process. If you model it with separate processes people that will look at the processes mostly won't understand that they belong together. You need to explicitly tell that the three processes are used for one scenario. If it is one process, the readers of the process can immediately see all aspects. Furthermore if you execute the process in Camunda you have better control of the process if it is one process instead of three separate processes.

Comment: I understand that the readability would be compromised on the process. But this would happen on the systems process and not on the Business Process. If I treat the two separately (as some tasks on the business process needn't be on the system), then I can abstract out that these are a set of different processes and represent it as a coherent system to the end user. The advantage I get is, changes can be handled very effectively as they are on different processes and very localised. Let me know if am missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I understood that your objective is to communicate a business process to users of a system. If so, then the first diagramme is in every way "better", i.e. it is

- **closer to the BPMN standard** : The three processes in the 2nd diagramme are not communicating with each other. How does the second process know that the payment has been accepted ? You would have to add either a signal or put the three processes into separate pools and make them exchange messages.
- **more desirable**. The three processes will be started at the same time in your 2nd diagramme. That means the task "Select payment method" could start (or worse finish) before you have even placed an order, which would not make any sense. As a business user (i.e. your assumed target audience) I would understand the 1st diagramme whereas the 2nd would give me riddles. The first diagramme makes the business logic more explicit and readable, which is exactly what BPMN has been developed for:

> "The primary goal of BPMN is to provide a notation that is readily
> understandable by all business users..." ([BPMN 2.0 Specification, page 1](https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0))

From your description, it seems as if your goal is actually to model a system and you are trying to adapt the business process design to reflect your system design (for example, you say that you prefer the second diagramme because the systems are de-coupled, which makes changes easier. But neither of the two diagrammes depict systems or system behaviour. The first diagramme could be implemented by using 12 systems while the second could be implemented with a single one.

If you really had to then you could use a pool for each of your three system and send messages back and forth as suggested above. But I would rather keep the 1st BPMN model (maybe with some minor corrections like the one MuffinMICHI has suggested) and use a separate UML sequence or component diagramme, where you explicitly model systems and their behaviour.

Comment: I understand that the diagram 2 isn't complete according to BPMN. My idea was to make a set of diagrams to explain the idea and thought process. Also, for readability, I would end up constructing a diagram to connecting all the processes together. Now that I see, maintainability becomes a nightmare when so many different things have to be kept in place to make things de coupled. 
It would be really helpful if you can mention some more issues related to making things de coupled in this scenario.

Comment: I would say if both diagrammes were formally correct then the only difference between the would be the degree of clarity or readability. I think the cost of adapting the two diagrammes due to changing business requirements (that is what you mean by maintainability, right?) should be more or less the same.